# How to prevent new line from showing on screen

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am having an editable `<p>` in which users adds comments ... when user hit enter their comments are submitted and posted in comment are ... its working pretty good but what the issue is that when enter is pressed the cursor moves to new line first and then it get posted ( have a look  at screen-shot just before comment is posted  the cursor appears in new line for few milliseconds).
here is my code :

```
$(document).on('keyup','.addComment',function(e) {

if (e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey!==true) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    var p_id = Number(id);
    var comment_box = '#comment_box_'+id;
    var content = $(comment_box).text();
    content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

    if (content.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update.php',
            data: ({content: content , id: p_id, act: "add_cmnt"}),
            success : function()
            {
                update_ca("comment_area_"+id);
                $(comment_box).text("");
            }
        }); // End of Ajax
    }
}

});
```

Now what i want is that when users hit enter the cursor should not be shown going in new line and the comment should be posted immediately ( without showing new line )
also note that the new line is showing up on screen only and not getting stored in database.
Here is code for `<p>` :

```
<p contenteditable="true" class=" addComment" id="comment_box_some_unique_id">
</p>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` at the top

Comment: I think we need to see that code for the `<p>` element. It might help.

Comment: @MakPo i have editted the post .. plz check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior when just pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Since you are using jQuery, use `return false` which will evaluate to `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` within a jQuery handler.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(".comment").on("keydown", function(e) {
//Check if Enter Key is pressed.
  if (e.which === 13) {

  //Check if Shift Key is pressed as well and keep default behavior.
  //This will stop function execution if enter + shift is pressed.
    if (e.shiftKey === true) return true; 

    //do Ajax Post here

    console.log($(this).text().trim()); //demo purposes
 
    //IMPORTANT: Prevent default behavior.
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="comment" contenteditable="true">
  Example Text
</p>
```

Comment: plz excuse me i am little bit confused ... where i have to put my ajax method ? can you please explain this to me a little more ? i shall be very thankful to you

Comment: Hello @Shehzad, look at the comments in the js code, there it specifies where it should be included.

Comment: my issue is that the cursor shows a glimpse of cursor being in new line first , before the comment is posted ... and then the comment get posted ( please look at the screen-shot ) hope you got my point

Comment: You removed the picture from your post.

Comment: Oh .. i didn't remove the picture and don't know how it get removed ... please see the picture here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zhx3.png

Answer (score 0):

Just use a jQuery method to prevent enter key.

```
$("#comment_box_some_unique_id").keypress(function(e){ return e.which != 13; });
```

Comment: Do not roll you answer back again. Backticks are for marking up inline code, **not** for hilighting arbitrary words.